# Calculating portfolio variance and volatility in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm fairly new to python 2.7 and I'm having a bit of trouble with calculating the variance and standard deviation of a portfolio of securities. This is what I have done so far:

1. Imported numpy, pandas, pandas_datareader and matplotlib.pyplot libraries
2. Imported all tickers and weights of the list of securities from an excel document (total of 9 tickers and weights)
3. Created separate lists to house both the tickers and weights
4. Downloaded all historical price data from google finance
5. Calculated daily logarithmic returns for each security and converted into yearly estimates
6. Calculated each securities estimated annual standard deviation and variance
7. Created covariance and correlation matrices
8. Changed the weights list into an array

Then I run into an error with the portfolio variance calculation. Here is the script I'm using:

```
# Portfolio variance calc
pfolio_var = np.dot(weightsarray.T, np.dot(sec_returns.cov() * 250, weightsarray))
pfolio_var

# Portfolio volatility
pfolio_vol = (np.dot(weightsarray.T, np.dot(sec_returns.cov() * 250, weightsarray))) ** 0.5
pfolio_vol

and here is the error I receive:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-6b33caaac89a> in <module>()
      1 # Portfolio variance calc
----> 2 pfolio_var = np.dot(weightsarray.T, np.dot(sec_returns.cov() * 250, weightsarray))
      3 pfolio_var

ValueError: shapes (9,9) and (1,9) not aligned: 9 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You may want to work with the transpose version of `weightsarray`, i.e. `weightsarray.T`. I mean, `pfolio_var = np.dot(weightsarray, np.dot(sec_returns.cov() * 250, weightsarray.T))`. Also consider reading [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That being said, welcome on SO.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, Kanak and boardrider. The transpose version worked great. I appreciate you adding the how to ask and minimal, complete, and verifiable example. I'll take a look at these links for future posts

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

Portfolio Variance

```
portfolio_variance=np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(log_returns.cov()*252,weights))
```

Portfolio Volatility

```
portfolio_vol = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(log_returns.cov()*252,weights)))
```